# Removing CarriageReturn ^M from certain lines in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, carriage-return, line-endings

I want to remove carriage returns from certain lines of code without modifying the whole document. If I do the usual `File > Advanced Save Options` it modifies the whole document, resulting in a full deletion + addition in my git diff. I rather not have that.

Is there another way, maybe through regex if possible. I'm on Visual Studio 2010.

I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and then using the Regex option with `/\r/` and `/\n/` but no luck.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Can you explain why you would want to do that on just some lines and not others?

Comment: Ah sorry! It seems that new changes introduced into the code have carriage returns, but the other lines don't. So the whole document is clean, but the new lines added all included carriage returns. So I rather not do the Advanced Save option to convert the whole document into Unix style line endings because that results in a diff I don't want in git (whole document modified)

Comment: Why would converting it to Unix-style line endings change anything but the lines with carriage returns?

Comment: Because running the Advanced Save option applies the line endings to the whole file, it seems to modify every line. I'm only seeing carriage returns on the newly added lines via `git diff --check`, and after the Advanced Save option, the whole file appears to be modified in the diff.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in visual studio 2013 community edition. Visual studio 2013 adds ^M to some lines especially #!/usr/bin/python , doesn't effect running on windows but does on linux and I'd prefer not having to open every file in vim to fix line endings. Fun of developing on windows but deploying on linux